# How can I write UTF-8 chars on java application?

Tags: java, netbeans, utf-8

I want to write

### ısı

to csv on java netbeans. It works fine when I debug the code. But when I clean and build the project, I run .jar application and then when I look the csv I see

### ?s?

How can I solve this ?

thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I use this to write :

```
 PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("myfile.csv")) ;              
    csvWriter.println("ısı") ;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using a compatible font for your console?

Comment: `System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");` may help, but it is hard to know if you don't show the code your using.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can help you if you don't include the code that writes the CSV in your question.

Comment: Also, have you changed the encoding of your project to UTF-8? Might default to Windows-1252 on Windows systems. But I'm speculating - I've stopped using netbeans years ago...

Comment: Does your CSV code expect ASCII or UTF-8?  You need to make sure you both write and read UTF-8.

Comment: I updated my code @VGR , when I run it on netbeans it works fine but when I run it on .jar , it shows **?s?**

Comment: @rossum java create csv file, how can I set csv to UTF-8 ?

Comment: What code do you use to open the CSV file?  There is often a parameter available, like the "UTF-8", in Jesper's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code:

```
PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("myfile.csv")) ;              
csvWriter.println("ısı") ;
```

you are using the default character encoding of your system, which may or may not be UTF-8. If you want to use UTF-8, you have to specify that:

```
PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("myfile.csv"), "UTF-8");
```

Note that even if you do this, you might still see unexpected output. If that's the case, then you will need to check if whatever program you use to display the output (the Windows command prompt, or a text editor, or ...) understands that the file is in UTF-8 and displays it correctly.